# Hibernate one to many mapping foreign key issue

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate. Please help me in understanding this.

I have Department and Employee objects. Department is having employee collection with cascade type SAVE.I have created department object and employee object.lets say dept1 and emp1 respectively.When I save dept1 object(which is having emp1) ,it is saving dept1 and emp1 in department and employee tables with out foreign key.

Unless I am setting department(dept1) on emp1 , it is not saving foreign key. why should i manually set that? can't hibernate do that? Is there any reason for doing that?

Comment: So how should Hibernate guess about your code? If you have both relationship (many-to-one and one-to-many), it is much better to set both relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how the Hibernate documentation and the JPA spec tells you to do it. In a bidirectional association, there's an owner side, and an inverse side. The owner side is the one which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute. The inverse side is the one which has the `mappedBy` attribute.

In a bidirectional OneToMany, the owner side is always the many side (the one which has the foerign key).

Hibernate/JPA only cares about the owner side. If you don't initialize the owner side, it considers the association doesn't exist. Unless you really know what you're doing, a good rule of thumb is to initialize both sides of the association, to make your graph of entities coherent.