# Hibernate One to One mapping not updating the JoinColumn id

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hibernate-mapping, ibm-rad

Not sure how to phrase the title for this.. so I'll just walkthrough the problem slowly.

Currently I'm working on a dynamic web project that uses `Struts2` and `Hibernate`. There isn't really enough documentation on the web that involves these 2. There's plenty of documentation and tutorial about them individually but rarely together. At most I would only find tutorial on how to integrate them or a simple CRUD that usually involve only one table.

What I have right now is 2 table, `Users` and `Profile` and I want to update both at the same time. I'll go into more detail on this later.

Here's my DB table:

```
Users
--------------
UserID
Email
Password
Status
userType

Profile
--------------
ProfileID
UserID
Name
Interest
ProfileDetails
```

I'm creating a registration page. In this page, the user will write down their name, email and password. As you can see, name is in the Profile table. I'm able to insert the email and password on the Users table as well as the Name into the Profile table. The problem is that the `UserID` is not being inserted into the Profile table.

My registration page has this form, which on submit will execute the addUser action.

```
<s:form action="addUser">
<s:push value="user">
    <s:hidden name="id" />
    <s:textfield name="profile.name" label="Name" />
    <s:textfield name="email" label="Email" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Password" />
    <s:submit />
</s:push>
</s:form>
```

My User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private String email;
private String password;
private Boolean status;
private Boolean userType;
private Profile profile;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Profile getProfile() {
    return profile;
}
public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="USERID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="EMAIL")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name="STATUS")
public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Column(name="USERTYPE")
public Boolean getUserType() {
    return userType;
}
public void setUserType(Boolean userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

public User() {}

public User(String email, String password, Boolean status, Boolean userType) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.status = status;
    this.userType = userType;
}
}
```

My Profile Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Profile")
public class Profile implements Serializable {

private Long profile_id;
private String name;
private String interest;
private String profile_details;
private User user;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="USERID")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="PROFILEID")
public Long getProfile_id() {
    return profile_id;
}
public void setProfile_id(Long profile_id) {
    this.profile_id = profile_id;
}

@Column(name="NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="INTEREST")
public String getInterest() {
    return interest;
}
public void setInterest(String interest) {
    this.interest = interest;
}

@Column(name="PROFILEDETAILS")
public String getProfile_details() {
    return profile_details;
}
public void setProfile_details(String profile_details) {
    this.profile_details = profile_details;
}
}
```

Is there a problem with my annotations or do I need to add something else in the form? Do let me know if you need any further details.

Also if you have a more in-depth tutorial on Struts2 + Hibernate do let me know..

Cheers!~

Comment: I answer this question twice a week. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603085/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-foreign-key-issue/11604354#11604354

Comment: Thanks for directing me to your answer. I'm still not too sure how to resolve my problem, I'm kinda new to Struts2 and Hibernate.

Base on your answer, my guess is that my addUser action should initialize the ProfileAction instead of the UserAction. Am I right? (shall try this one out)

Comment: No. You should just make sure that the `Profile.user` field is initialized, and not just the `User.profile` field, since `Profile.user` is the owner side.

Comment: Oh wow, that actually solved it (Using ProfileAction instead of UserAction). Thanks man although I don't think that this is the proper way haha :)

Not too sure about what you meant by initializing the Profile.user.. so I'll probably stick to this for now.

Comment: `user.setProfile(profile); // not sufficient` `profile.setUser(user); // now the owner side is initialized, and Hibernate will persist the association`.

Comment: Still don't get it where I'm supposed to be adding that.. T___T really really sorry >___<

Comment: @Sayid Hafiz Did you get the solution for this problem. I too facing the same issue ?